# Google Analytics Reporting Some Traffic as "Direct" from ExactTarget Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, analytics

We have been troubleshooting an issue with email tracking from our ExactTarget emails for months now, and I am turning here hoping someone smarter than our team can come up with some suggestions that we might be able to look into.

Over the past 6-months we have started to run into an issue with tracking email success through Google Analytics from our emails sent through ExactTarget. We suddenly saw a major drop in all of our email performance in Google Analytics which was concerning, but when we look at it in more detail, the same drop in performance from emails saw and similar increase in performance and traffic attributed as "Direct" in GA.

Every email we send, we suddenly see a "boost" in GA "direct" traffic. Which seems to tell us that something is happening with the tracking and GA is not attributing all of the traffic to the ET emails.

We have tried moving from a dynamic insertion of the campaign name so hard coding it in every email and we have also made our campaign names super simple with no spaces or special characters to try and eliminate anything that could be causing this odd behavior.

We are at a loss. Any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

### Update 1:

We have isolated this down to being related to newer versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have SFMC support verify your [Web Analtyics Connector](https://help.exacttarget.com/no/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/) (WAC) configuration.  Also you need to make sure that your emails are all set to have tracking enabled:

[image: Track all Links]

Comment: We actually manually add all of the Google Analytics querystrings manually in each link rather than having ET populate those for us.

Comment: That's the hard way to go about it.  WAC strings can include AMPScript variables.